# Can't conect to SQL 2008 R2 Express with Encrypt connection checked (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11001)

Tags: sql, ssl-certificate

I can connect with "Encrypt connection" if I'm connecting locally, I can connect without "Encrypt connection" remotely, but I ***can't connect remotely with "Encrypt connection" checked.***

The error that I get from ssms: 
"A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is known.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 11001)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=11001&LinkId=20476"

My host just sent me a certificate, I added the certificate both to the Trusted root CA and Trusted publishes.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: 11001 = WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND which matches your error message. Are you sure you've got the hostname correct? The full host name? Not sure why that would vary between encrypted and not, though (unless it's failing trying to find a server for CRL lookup or something).

Comment: Hi Rup, the only possible thought I have is that I explicitly provide the port (SERVER\INSTANCENAME,1433) and not relying on the Browser, not sure if it is relevant, It is the only "exception" i can think of. For the server I use the IP Address

Answer (score 1):

In case it will save someone else some pain, using the server name instead of the IP Address solved the problem.